# How can i center a button inside of a div tag, to make it responsive for toggle device toolbar in Angular 8

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, ng-bootstrap

***I have the following problem:*** i have a `<div>` and inside of that tag i have a button, but i cant center the button vertically and horizontally inside the `<div>` also i want the button to be center for phones for that i saw it `toggle device toolbar`

***Really dont know how to solve it, im new using Angular***

- Below i will let the code of my `<div>` that has the button inside, the picture of how the button is displayed[image] also i'm using `Angular material`

***Div tag code***

```html
<div *ngIf="nav_bar==false" class="colour large">
  <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label="Example icon-button with a menu">
    <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="'/'">
      <mat-icon>dialpad</mat-icon>
      <span>Inicio</span>
    </button>
    <button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="['/nosotros']">
      <mat-icon>voicemail</mat-icon>
      <span>Nosotros</span>
    </button>
    <button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="['/contacto']">
      <mat-icon>notifications_off</mat-icon>
      <span>Contacto</span>
    </button>
  </mat-menu>
<button class="mat-button col-xs-3" (click)="nav_bar=!nav_bar">
   <img src="./assets/icons/baseline_visibility_white_18dp.png" class="mdc-icon-button__icon"/>
</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an angular thing, it's an html/css thing. If you're going to use bootstrap you might want to check out the grid documentation a bit to better familiarize yourself with how it works, along with the utility classes. Something like this would probably be more what you're looking for.

```html
<div *ngIf="nav_bar==false" class="colour large d-flex align-items-center">
  <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label="Example icon-button with a menu">
    <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="'/'">
      <mat-icon>dialpad</mat-icon>
      <span>Inicio</span>
    </button>
    <button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="['/nosotros']">
      <mat-icon>voicemail</mat-icon>
      <span>Nosotros</span>
    </button>
    <button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="['/contacto']">
      <mat-icon>notifications_off</mat-icon>
      <span>Contacto</span>
    </button>
  </mat-menu>
  <button class="mat-button mx-auto" (click)="nav_bar=!nav_bar">
     <img src="./assets/icons/baseline_visibility_white_18dp.png" class="mdc-icon-button__icon"/>
  </button>
</div>
```